# What could be eating through my drywall

Tags: drywall, damage, pest

Tonight I noticed this section of my wall in the basement. It looked like something had been eating through the drywall. The area is so tight and I know 100% that it wasn't damaged by me. So what problem could I have? I live in Ontario, Canada. I'm calling in pest control to have a look but that might not happen for 2-3 days. Here are pictures of the damage

[image]
[image]

Comment: Whatever is eating it is also using a utility knife!

Comment: really? I'm a noob at these things. It is definitely not my area of expertise. I've owned the house for 5 years now and I have never noticed it before. I've had two sets of painters through as well which is why I thought for sure it was something new.

Comment: Pests rarely if ever cut in straight lines., and usually leave tooth-marks.

Answer (score 2):

Since the Pest Controller didn't find any pest cause or problem, very good news. Go ahead & patch, tape & mud it. Make sure the patch doesn't touch the masonry. The moisture down there may get it again or any paper break. If it starts happening all over, eventually, then painted fiberglass faced drywall would last or you might opt for cement board at that time. But, just patch what you've got to gauge what works & what doesn't & for how long.

Comment: Thanks for the input guys I will update once I hear back from them or get them to come in.

Comment: I talked to a pest control guy. I showed him the pictures and he says that it wasn't caused by any pests. Just patch up :)

Comment: Beautiful!!! Go ahead & patch, tape & mud it. Make sure the patch doesn't touch the masonry. The moisture down there may get it again or any paper break. If it starts happening all over, eventually, then painted fiberglass faced drywall would last indefinitely or you might opt for cement board at that time. But, just patch what you've got to gauge what works & what doesn't & for how long.